# How to save command pattern commands on a button?

Tags: android, kotlin, design-patterns, command-pattern

I have an app where I want the user to be able to select from a list of possible actions and ascribe them to a button, i.e. button a call mom, slider b sets a timer... etc..

I've built a load of command classes and my buttons / sliders have a command 'slot' following the command pattern.

But how do I save the users selection? My persistent data is in JSON, what would I store in JSON? Some kind of reference to the class name?

In command pattern tutorials, the example is often given of it's use on context menus allowing the user to assign actions to menu options but they never mention how the user selection is actually saved.

Comment: Serialization is outside the scope of most design patterns. In fact you can serialize the objects any way you like (or not at all) and satisfy the Command pattern. There are many libraries dedicated to object serialization; but if some other form of identifier is sufficient for you to deserialize the Command and you don't need to serialize the complete object, that works too.

Comment: Thanks. I took a look at serialisation ( read some articles and watched a 30 minute lecture ). All the given examples are for classes with properties, not functions with parameters that are only known at run time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Memento Design Pattern.
With this pattern you can store user actions in memory and also you can have a history of actions and undo or redo them if the user wants.

You can read more [here](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/memento)
Here a sample

> ```
> public class Memento {
>    private String state;
>
>    public Memento(String state){
>       this.state = state;
>    }
>
>    public String getState(){
>       return state;
>    }  
> }
>
>
> public class Originator {
>    private String state;
>
>    public void setState(String state){
>       this.state = state;
>    }
>
>    public String getState(){
>       return state;
>    }
>
>    public Memento saveStateToMemento(){
>       return new Memento(state);
>    }
>
>    public void getStateFromMemento(Memento memento){
>       state = memento.getState();
>    }
> }
>
> import java.util.ArrayList;
> import java.util.List;
>
> public class CareTaker {
>    private List<Memento> mementoList = new ArrayList<Memento>();
>
>    public void add(Memento state){
>       mementoList.add(state);
>    }
>
>    public Memento get(int index){
>       return mementoList.get(index);
>    }
> }
>
>
> public class MementoPatternDemo {
>    public static void main(String[] args) {
>    
>       Originator originator = new Originator();
>       CareTaker careTaker = new CareTaker();
>       
>       originator.setState("State #1");
>       originator.setState("State #2");
>       careTaker.add(originator.saveStateToMemento());
>       
>       originator.setState("State #3");
>       careTaker.add(originator.saveStateToMemento());
>       
>       originator.setState("State #4");
>       System.out.println("Current State: " + originator.getState());      
>       
>       originator.getStateFromMemento(careTaker.get(0));
>       System.out.println("First saved State: " + originator.getState());
>       originator.getStateFromMemento(careTaker.get(1));
>       System.out.println("Second saved State: " + originator.getState());
>    }
> }
>
>
> Verify the output.
>
>
> Current State: State #4
> First saved State: State #2
> Second saved State: State #3
> ```